# ksh remote function calling another remote function3

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, ksh

```sh
#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function test_me
{
set -x
date
}

function check_me 
{
set -x
ssh HST2 "$(typeset -f test_me); test_me"
}

ssh HST1 "$(typeset -f); check_me"
```

Fails with: `syntax error at line 5:` ;;' unexpected` can some on help ?

from sath I am logging on Oracle RAC cluster. I login on first node of RAC1A, then prepare list of database on this RAC1, on various node RAC1B, RAC1C, RAC1D. then login on each of RAC1B and connect to DB. $HST1 and $HST2 is just to hide the hostname, you can put anything you like. SATH ==> RAC1A ===> RAC1B. Where HST1 is RAC1A and HST2 is RAC1B –

IF you have any 3 paired server where ssh keys is rolled out in SATH ==> RAC1A ===> RAC1B, you can test above code. SATH ==> HST1 ===> HST2

Comment: what does `typeset -f` generate when run on the local machine? what does `$(typeset -f)` generate when run on the local machine? also, where is the `Fails with syntax error` occurring ... local machine? 2nd machine? 3rd machine?

Comment: local  machine typeset -f .. shows correct definition. HST1 also shows correct definition.. Only HST2 shows extra `;` and fails with ksh syntax error line 5 `;;' unexpected

Comment: if I test function in alphabetical order with inner function then it works :` #!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function a
{
set -x
date
}

function b 
{
set -x
ssh HST2 "$(typeset -f a); a"
}

ssh HST1 "$(typeset -f); b"`

Comment: But If I test in reverse albhabetical order for inner function then it fails : `#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function b
{
set -x
date
}

function a
{
set -x
ssh HST2 "$(typeset -f b); b"
}

ssh HST1 "$(typeset -f); a"`

Comment: Not sure if its ksh bug .. but depend on how functions are alphabetically ordered.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function a
{
set -x
date
}

function b
{
set -x
ssh HST2 "$(typeset -f a); a"
}

ssh HST1 "$(typeset -f); b"
```

Above code works fine where inner function is alphabetical order ascending..

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function b
{
set -x
date
}

function a
{
set -x
ssh HST2 "$(typeset -f b); b"
}

ssh HST1 "$(typeset -f); a"
```

Above code fails where inner function name is alphabetical order descending..
Fails with syntax error at line 5: `;;' unexpected